# Action bar import for V

Tags: android

```
package com.example.QBank;

//import android.app.ActionBar;
//import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.example.QBank.R;


public class HomeScreen extends Activity {
//public class HomeScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
Button butQB1,butQB2,butQB3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        }
    else
    {
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar()
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    }

    //for color
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#22ac38")));
    addListenerOnButton();
```

I am trying to fix the action bar problem in my code,but in vain.
I am trying to make my app from API 7. But is having some problem with actionbar.

Kindly help me.
Thanks

Comment: What is your problem? Is there error? Can't understand what you want

Answer (score 1):

Well, I see something really weird.

1 - You were correctly extending from `ActionBarActivity`, then reverted back to `Activity` - **It won't work**.
2 - You are trying to set a different ActionBar for different OS versions... **It won't work**.
    Just use the ActionBarCompat for all OS versions and that's it (leave only the **else** part of your **if**).
I'm successfully using it on API Level **8 - 19**.

Comment: I wanted my app to work with API 7 version. I am facing issue with   this part of the code. How to make getActiobar work for API7?                                                                      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        }
       else
    {
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar()
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    }

Comment: Apart that API level 7 is nowadays used by **less than the 0.1%** of the world Android users... If you **follow my advices** (both) it will work. I'm using it on **API Level 8 - 19** with success.